# How to target a different host inside a Fabric command

Tags: python, fabric

How do you specify a different target to run a command on other than the one that's currently set for the running Fabric command?

I have a command download_backup() that downloads a database backup file to the localhost from a remote host. Since it has to run locally, the host_string is localhost. However, I need to run a command on the remote host to find what the most recent backup is. When I try to do:

```
def download_backup():
    env.host_string = 'remotehost'
    env.user = 'remoteuser'
    backup_fn = run('ls -t /usr/local/lib/backups | head -1')
```

it still attempts to run the `ls` command on localhost. I do I change this to run on remotehost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use the settings context manager to change the host that a specific command runs on, independent of the host setting for the enclosing task.

```
from fabric.context_managers import settings
with settings(host_string='remote_server'):
    run('ls -lart')
```

Comment: Oddly, this does not fix the problem.

Comment: @Cerin, what version of Fabric are you running?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I was also using cuisine, which overrides fabric's run() method, and apparently cuisine's run() negates the effects of settings(). When I removed cuisine, your solution works.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the reason your command is run on localhost is because `env` is a global variable and you are overriding it locally but that is not being seen when fabric is running the commands.  You should define your host_string outside of your function.

```
env.host_string = 'remotehost'
env.user = 'remoteuser'

def download_backup():
    run('ls -t /usr/local/lib/backups | head -1')
```

To change hosts at runtime you have a couple of options.  First, you can utilize the `roles` and `roledefs` functionality.

```
env.roledefs = {
    "ex1": ["host1.example.com"],
    "ex2": ["host2.example.com"],
    }
env.roles = ["ex1"]

def download_backup():
    run("ls -t /usr/local/lib/backups | head -1")
```

By default when you run `fab download_backup` you will get the backup from `host1.example.com` because env.roles is set to `ex1`.  If you wish to override that setting you can specify the role via the command line:

```
fab -R ex2 download_backup
```

This would initiate fabric with the role `ex2` and would thus obtain it's backup from `host2.example.com` instead.

The other option would be to make use of the fact that `env` is just a global variable.

```
def download_backup():
    run("ls -t /usr/local/lib/backups | head -1")

def download_backup_ex1():
    global env
    env.host_string = "host1.example.com"
    download_backup()

def download_backup_ex2():
    global env
    env.host_string = "host2.example.com"
    download_backup()
```

I personally prefer the first method as it obviously lends itself better to what is being done in this case, but I can imagine there are possibilities where the second approach might be the better alternative.

Comment: Although I appreciate your effort, you're incorrect about the cause being env is global. Using `global` is only necessary when I want to redefine the name binding of `env`, which I'm not. When setting a variable inside env, Python will automatically using the global env binding. And as I expected, adding `global env` to my function does not fix the problem.

Comment: I apologize for being incorrect about the use of global. Perhaps you can clarify what you are trying to do if the first example I provided doesn't solve your problem though.

Comment: He wants to delegate a subtask to a different host than the one running the main task, I suspect.